# Getting results from an Oracle package function returning a table

Tags: oracle, plsql

Our database has a package that returns a type `t_daily_array_table`.

This type is defined as:

```
  TYPE t_daily_array_table IS TABLE OF r_daily_array_rec
```

and `r_daily_array_rec` is defined as a record with a number of fields.

We have a package called `schedule_pkg` with the function `f_daily_array_table` which returns the `t_daily_array_table`. The function takes a single `Number` parameter.

I've tried calling it a number of ways, but I can't seem to get it to work (I know this function works. It's called from an COBOL app that functions just fine).

I've tried:

```
select schedule_pkg.f_daily_array_table(74501) from dual;
```

When I do that, I get

```
SQL Error: ORA-00902: invalid datatype
```

I've tried:

```
select * from schedule_pkg.f_daily_array_table(74501)
```

That gives me:

```
SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

I've tried using code (C#) and calling in various ways using OleDb, OracleClient, and ODBC and I have yet to find a way I can call this, other than using COBOL.

Comment: You're trying to refer to a PL/SQL type from a SQL context, which won't work. How is your COBOL code processing the result? You should be able to do something similar from a PL/SQL block or an OCI program. What do you want to do with the table contents?

Comment: @AlexPoole I merely want to examine the returned data, for now. In MS SQL, one can simply call a stored procedure, even if it returns the equivalent of a table. Can you not do the same in Oracle?

Comment: @Pete this is not how it works in Oracle. Closest to what you're looking for is pipelined table function [link](http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/pipelined-table-functions.php)

Comment: @Pete - you can, sort of; but only with a schema-level SQL table type; not a PL/SQL collection type. Presumably the COBOL version is using an array descriptor, which you can do from Java or C. You could use a separate pipelined function to convert from one type to another, perhaps, as ms32035 mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to query the values from an SQL context but have a PL/SQL collection type, you can create a pipelined wrapper function, either within the package or as a standalone object for testing/debuggging. Something like this should work:

```
create function f_daily_array_pipe(p_id IN number)
return schedule_pkg.t_daily_array_table pipelined is
  l_daily_array_table schedule_pkg.t_daily_array_table;
begin
  l_daily_array_table := schedule_pkg.f_daily_array_table(p_id);
  for i in 1..l_daily_array_table.count loop
    pipe row (l_daily_array_table(i));
  end loop;
end f_daily_array_pipe;
/

select * from table(f_daily_array_pipe(74501));
```

This calls your original function, assigns the result to a local collection, iterates over it, and pipes each record in turn back to the caller; which uses the SQL `table()` collection expression to convert it to something you can query from.

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6ea8e/1).

If you are using an OCI or JDBC client you can use an array descriptor and retrieve the data as an array, but that won't work from plain SQL.

Comment: I've tried this. I get an error from the compiler: "pipelined functions must have a supported collection return type."

Comment: I think it's this. I missed this in the original post (sorry): `TYPE t_daily_array_table IS TABLE OF r_daily_array_rec INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;` You can't use `index by` in pipelined functions. How can I get around that?

Answer (score 0):

I think the syntax you're looking for is:

```
select * from table(schedule_pkg.f_daily_array_table(74501));
```

Comment: That would work if it was an SQL type (i.e. defined at schema level), but it will get an invalid data type error with  a PL/SQL collection type (defined in a package).